# Не скачивается Pygame

Tags: python, pygame, pip

[image: Вот первая ошибка]

я так же скачивал архив tar.gz с pygame и открывал файл setup.py но и там ничего не работало
[image: Вот вторая ошибка]

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Вот тут почитайте варианты https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3691188/pygame-installation-on-windows-error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй обновить Python на последнюю версию, доступную на сайте.

Comment: стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос

Comment: Как раз под последнюю версию python нужная библиотека может быть и не обновлена. Имеет смысл наоборот попробовать более старую версию Python, например 3.8, 3.9, 3.10 (смотря какая сейчас установлена).

Comment: Спасибо вам insolor, у меня была последняя версия Python, 3.11.1, я скачал прошлую 3.10.9 и всё сработало

Answer (score 0):

Перед установкой pygame нужно установить whell - `pip install whell`. У консоли в VS code бывают иногда свои ошибки. Лучше использовать обычный powershell или cmd. Если не сработает, попробуйте `pip install --user pygame`

Comment: Ничего не сработало(